# Error next '=' after update statement in T.SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute a trigger, and I have the following error linked to this part of my script:

```
EXEC (N'update CMDB2' + '_CI_' + @CI_TYPE_ID)

SET STATUS =  'RESERVE'

WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie  = @variable and STATUS = 'En stock'
```

The error is :

> Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Procedure CHANGEMENT_ETAT_CI_EN RESERVATION, Ligne 58
>   Syntaxe incorrecte vers '='.

after set order.

Everything goes fine if I specify the table name exactly, in the `update` statement, otherwise if I specify the table name as a concatenated strings and variable the problem shows up.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This code

> SET STATUS =  'RESERVE' WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie  =
>   @variable and STATUS = 'En stock'

is outside the exec statement, must be inside it.